# Couchbase error System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream

Tags: c#, .net-core, couchbase

We are using couchbase .Netcore client SDK and we have started using Couchbase.Extensions.DependencyInjection library to connect to couchbase in our .netcore web api, our application is working fine, but we are seeing error logs in the cloudwatch which says,

System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
at System.IO.Stream.set_ReadTimeout(Int32 value)
at Couchbase.Configuration.Server.Providers.Streaming.ConfigThreadState.ListenForConfigChanges()

Properties.SourceContext
Couchbase.Configuration.Server.Providers.Streaming.ConfigThreadState

This is how we configured db connection in our startup.cs class. We are using named buckets in our application.

Can someone help us out what exactly that means? Also do we need to worry about this error?

```
services.AddCouchbase(opt =>
               {
                   opt.Servers = new List<Uri> { new Uri("server_url") };
               })
        .AddCouchbaseBucket<IDCCBucket>("BucketName", "Pass**rd");
```

Comment: What version of Couchbase Server are you using?

Comment: @MatthewGroves we are using 6.0.2 version.

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but it looks like you're trying to use a bucket password, but Couchbase changed the way authentication works in 5.x and so you don't use bucket passwords anymore. Maybe checkout https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/security/upgrading-to-rbac.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @MatthewGroves, that really helped!

Comment: @MatthewGroves, each time when we deploy our pods in eks, I see this exception "System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
at System.IO.Stream.set_ReadTimeout(Int32 value)
at Couchbase.Configuration.Server.Providers.Streaming.ConfigThreadState.ListenForConfigChanges()"

Comment: Is there any way you can narrow down where the error is happening in the code? Perhaps create a minimal example of C# that causes this error?

Comment: We were able to resolve it @MatthewGroves. There was an issue with the couchbase cluster that was configured on aws. Our team was able to resolve it. Thanks alot for the help though!

Comment: @ManikanthReddy, can you elaborate on your AWS fix to resolve this? We have the same issue.

Comment: @ManikanthReddy can any one have solution? we also have same issue